# Ruby on Rails link_to tag with mouseenter jQuery function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have an image appear in a `div` when `mouseenter` using `link_to` in rails. The below code works but I'm not clear on how it's running.

```
<a href="#" class="nav-link roll"> <%= image_tag("chair1.jpg") %>Chesterfield Chair Set</a>
```

My jQuery is:

```
$(".roll").hover(function(){
  $('.chair-img').css({'background':'url('+ $(this).attr('src')
   });
});
```

Looking for the correct way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean it is working or not working?

Comment: It does work but from what I know of Ruby on Rails (which is not a lot) it's not the correct syntax. I would like to know the correct way of achieving this to improve on what I have and get it right in the future.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. There is no `.chair-img` element in the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to '#', class: 'nav-link roll' do %>
   <%= image_tag("chair1.jpg")
   Chesterfield Chair Set
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure this work perfectly but the idea is wrap image an text inside block of `link_to` helper

Comment: Thanks for your solution but this will show the image_tag. What I need is for the image to show only when the link_to has mouseenter and change back when mouseleave.

Comment: I found a jsfiddle of the effect I am trying to replicate with Ruby on Rails. http://jsfiddle.net/J8FJq/105/. I hope this helps to explain what I am trying to do better.